# Build Tree::Simple object from file data

Tags: perl, tree

Does anyone have any experience of using [`Tree::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tree%3a%3aSimple) or putting data into a tree in Perl?

Say I have the following CSV file of data:-

```
Bob, Bill, Ben, Brett
Bob, Bill, Brian
Bob, John, Jim
Alice, John, Jill, Jane
Alice, Jean
Alice, Janet, Brian
```

I would like to convert it into a tree structure in order to obtain the following:

```
1, Bob
2, Alice
1.1, Bill
1.1.1, Ben
1.1.1.1, Brett
1.1.2, Brian
1.2, John
1.2.1, Jim
2.1, John
2.1.1, Jill
2.1.1.1, Jane
2.2, Jean
2.3, Janet
2.3.1, Brian
```

I have looked at `Tree::Simple` and know that if I can get the data into a tree I can use [`Tree::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tree%3a%3aParser) to output it with the correct numbering.

What I would like is an an example of how I could input the data line by line.  I could start by reading each line of the file into an array, and adding `$array[0]` in as the first child - e.g.

```
$tree->addChildren(Tree::Simple->new($array[0]));
```

What I don't know how to do is:

1. Check whether there already is a child with that name in the tree, so that I don't add say Bob in twice.
2. Find the correct parent for each child so that say Jill is entered as a child of the John who is the child of Alice, not the child of Bob

I would much appreciate some help on this problem. I've been working on it for 4 days and cannot get there.  If `Tree::Simple` is not the best way of doing this, perhaps there is another way?

Comment: Note that your data has, for instance, John as the son of both Alice and Bob. `Tree::Simple` implements n-ary trees which do not support nodes with multiple parents. Is this a problem or is your data unrepresentative?

Answer (score 1):

This program reads the sample data you have shown from the `DATA` filehandle and appears to do what you need.

It keeps track of all the nodes in the tree by putting them in a hash indexed by each node's value. Every time a value appears in the input file the hash is checked to see if a node for it already exists. If not then a new tree node is created and added to the hash. Either way the node is used as the parent for the next value on the same line.

There is no check for consistency of the data, and it is assumed that every node has at most one parent. If a value appears a second time in the data file beneath a different parent name the new association is ignored.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tree::Simple;
use Tree::Parser;

my %nodes;

my $root = Tree::Simple->new('root');

while (<DATA>) {
  my $parent = $root;
  for my $name (split) {
    $name =~ tr/,//d;
    $nodes{$name} = Tree::Simple->new($name, $parent) unless $nodes{$name};
    $parent = $nodes{$name};
  }
}

my $tp = Tree::Parser->new($root);
$tp->useDotSeparatedLevelFilters;
print "$_\n" for $tp->deparse

__DATA__
Bob, Bill, Ben, Brett
Bob, Bill, Brian
Bob, John, Jim
Alice, John, Jill, Jane
Alice, Jean
Alice, Janet, Brian
```

**output**

```
1 Bob
1.1 Bill
1.1.1 Ben
1.1.1.1 Brett
1.1.2 Brian
1.2 John
1.2.1 Jim
1.2.2 Jill
1.2.2.1 Jane
2 Alice
2.1 Jean
2.2 Janet
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - this gets me round the problem of repeating a node of the same value.  However, I really need to keep duplicate values if they have different parents - i.e. John needs to appear as a child of bob and a child of alice; and jane needs to be a grandchild of alice, not a grandchild of bob - I just can't see how to do this.

Comment: Then you have chosen the wrong data structure. As I said, nodes in n-ary trees can have only one parent. The solution is *not* to add a second node with the same value but a different parent, but you must explain your purpose before I can recommend a different way of doing things. What do you want to do with the tree once you have built it? You said was it was "in order to obtain the [numbered output]" but clearly there is more to it.

Comment: My program has to produce input for a 3rd party package, which uses it to create drop down hierarchical menus and sub-menus on a web page.  
So, e.g. there would be 2 top level menus, bob and alice, and each of these top menus would have a sub-menu john.  Although both called john they are actually different items. 
The sub-sub-menu item jill would go in as a sub-menu of the john that is the sub-menu of alice, but not of bob.  
The data has to go into the program in a file of the format:- number, data, parent number e.g.
1, bob,0
2,alice,0
1.1., bill,1
1.1.1, ben, 1.1