# To calculate the averages in csv file using perl as move up file collecting numbers

Tags: perl, csv, average

I have a CSV file with three columns in order called Mb_size, tax_id, and parent_id. There is a relationship between tax_id and parent_id, for example, in the csv file at the end where you have 22.2220658537 for the mb size, 5820 is the tax id and 5819 is the parent id. As move up the file 5819 the parent id will be seen in the tax id column. The parent id can be repeated but tax id is uniqie in its column.

Starting at the end which has values in Mb_size, I need to work up to the top calculating the average everytime the parent_id becomes the tax_id. Then move up by when this happens the parent Id that is next to that tax Id become new start point to move up.

Below is the sample input :

```
Mb_size,tax_id,parent_id
,1,1
,131567,1
,2759,131567
,5819,2759
,147429,2759
22.2220658537,5820,5819
184.801317,4557,147429
748.66869,4575,147429
555.55,1234,5819
```

Below is the sample output:

```
 Mb_size,tax_id,parent_id
 377.810518214,1,1
 377.810518214,131567,1
 377.810518214,2759,131567
 288.886032927,5819,2759
 466.7350035,147429,2759
 22.2220658537,5820,5819
 184.801317,4557,147429
 748.66869,4575,147429
 555.55,1234,5819,
```

The code so far

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 no warnings 'numeric';

  open taxa_fh, '<', "$ARGV[0]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[1]" for input: $!\n};
  open match_fh, ">$ARGV[0]_sized.csv" or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};

  my %data;

  while ( my $line = <taxa_fh> ) {

  chomp( $line );

    my @fields    = split( /,/, $line );
    my $Mb_size   = $fields[0];
    my $tax_id    = $fields[1];
    my $parent_id = $fields[2];

    $data{$parent_id}{sum} += $Mb_size;
    $data{$parent_id}{count}++;
   }

    for my $parent_id ( sort keys %data ) {
    my $avg = $data{$parent_id}{sum} / $data{$parent_id}{count};
    print match_fh "$parent_id, $avg \n";

    }

   close taxa_fh;
   close match_fh;
```

The code I have so far, is from a poster of help earlier. I edited the question to help make it better/clearer. I cant get it to continue the calculation up and include in the printing the original lines from below.
I tried a foreach(tax_id) but didn't work. Any suggestions to include to accomplish this . It does move up but doesn’t do calculation.

Comment: You have data with parent-child relationships, so you are constructing a tree.  Build a tree, then for each node, calculate the average of all of its descendent nodes.  Try `Tree::Simple` and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505931/build-treesimple-object-from-file-data

Comment: Does the order matters while printing?

Comment: No not while printing. Just as long as the maths is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need build a data-structure carefully from down to up first. I am using `hashes` for that.

Here for every `parent_id` as key I am building a hash in which I am saving `averages`,`tax_id`,`sum` and `count` associated with that.

As there could be multiple `tax_id` associated with single parent_id we need to store averages separately for them.

Now when It becomes a tree like structure then It becomes trivial to print it out according to our requirements. 
As they are hashes, orders are not conserved. To maintain order you can use `arrays` instead of `hashes`.

One way to do it will be like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'tax' or die "unable to open file:$!\n";

my %data;
my @lines;
chomp(my $header=<$fh>); #slurp header
while(<$fh>){
chomp;
my @fields=split(/,/);
  if($fields[0]){
     ##actually field0 is avg so storing it as avg here
    $data{$fields[2]}{$fields[1]}{avg}=$fields[0];
    $data{$fields[2]}{sum}+=$fields[0];
    $data{$fields[2]}{count}++;
  }
  else{
       push(@lines,[split(/,/)]);
     }
}
close($fh);
@lines=reverse @lines;
foreach my $lines(@lines){
 if(exists $data{$lines->[1]}){
     $data{$lines->[2]}{$lines->[1]}{avg}=($data{($lines->[1])}{sum})/($data{($lines->[1])}{count});
     $data{$lines->[2]}{sum}+=$data{$lines->[2]}{$lines->[1]}{avg};
     $data{$lines->[2]}{count}++;
 }
else{
   print "Sorry No Such Entry ",$lines->[2]," present\n";
 }
}
print "$header\n";
foreach my $tax_id(keys %data){
    foreach my $parent_id(keys $data{$tax_id} ){
       if(ref ($data{$tax_id}{$parent_id}) eq 'HASH'){
          print $data{$tax_id}{$parent_id}->{'avg'}.",".$tax_id.",".$parent_id."\n";
       }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another similar solution, based on your work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open taxa_fh, '<', "$ARGV[0]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[1]" for input: $!\n};
open match_fh, ">$ARGV[0]_sized.csv" or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};

my %node_data;
my %parent;
my @node_order;
my $header;
while ( my $line = <taxa_fh> ) {
    chomp( $line );

    if (1 == $.) {
        $header = $line;
        next; # Skip header
    }

    my @fields    = split( /,/, $line );
    my $Mb_size   = $fields[0] || 0; # To avoid uninitialized warning
    my $tax_id    = $fields[1];
    my $parent_id = $fields[2];

    $parent{$tax_id} = $parent_id;
    push @node_order, $tax_id;
    $node_data{$tax_id} = $Mb_size;
}

# Add the node value for all parents in the tree
my %totals;
for my $tax_id ( sort keys %parent ) {
    my $parent = $parent{$tax_id};
    my $done = 0;
    while( ! $done ) {
        if ($node_data{$tax_id} > 0) {
            $totals{$parent}->{sum} += $node_data{$tax_id};
            $totals{$parent}->{count}++;
        }
        $done++ if ($parent{$parent} == $parent);
        $parent = $parent{$parent};
    }
}

print match_fh "$header\n";
for my $id ( @node_order ) {
    my $avg;
    if ( exists $totals{$id} ) {
        # Parent Node
        $avg = $totals{$id}->{sum} / $totals{$id}->{count};        
    } else {
        # Leaf Node
        $avg = $node_data{$id};
    }

    print match_fh "$avg, $id, " . $parent{$id} . "\n";
}

close taxa_fh;
close match_fh;
```

**Output:**

```
Mb_size,tax_id,parent_id
377.810518213425, 1, 1
377.810518213425, 131567, 1
377.810518213425, 2759, 131567
288.88603292685, 5819, 2759
466.7350035, 147429, 2759
22.2220658537, 5820, 5819
184.801317, 4557, 147429
748.66869, 4575, 147429
555.55, 1234, 5819
```